# Tomcat: issue to create a local keystore on Windows

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, keystore

When I try to create a local keystore on Windows with:

```
 keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

after inserting yes, I ask again for the info already entered, that is:

What is your first and last name?

What is the name of your organizational unit?

What is the name of your organization?

What is the name of your City or Locality?

What is the name of your State or Province?

What is the two-letter country code for this unit?

I don't know the reason why of this loop.

**EDIT**

Resolved: I had to enter the "yes" in my SO language at the confirmation question

Answer (score 0):

In fact you are generating an RSA keypair, which in turn generates x509 certificate to store the public part of your RSA key. These certificates also contain identification items like the ones you mention.

Comment: In the docs I read 'This command will create a new file, in the home directory of the user under which you run it, named ".keystore"'. That questions are prompted again and again.

Comment: It will generate a new keypair in your keystore, and if the keystore does not exist, create one. Have you entered "yes" when asked "Is CN=... correct"? If not,that's the reason it might loop.

Comment: I've entered "yes", but alle the questions are represented again and again. I tried "yes", "y", but now I'm thinking if it could be internationalized, so I'll try "yes" in my own language.

Comment: Maybe add a transcript of at leat one loop including all inputs

Comment: I resolved. It wanted the "yes" in my SO language ("si" without the accent on letter i)